# Is it better to avoid declaring a function too many times for performance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have a function `a`, which will be executed many times (thousands).

Inside the `a` function there is a `util` function, which is ONLY used inside `a`.

Now I have two options:

First, put the `util` inside `a`. It won't "pollute" the outside scope but will be declared once every time `a` is called.

Second, put the `util` outside `a`. It will do the reverse.

Which one is better for performance?

Option 1:

```
while(xx){
  a();
}
function a(){
  util();
  function util(){
    // will only stay inside a()
    // but will be declared everytime when a is called.
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
while(xx){
  a();
}
function a(){
  util();
}
function util(){
  // only declare once but will be accessed by all other scope outside a().   
}
```

Comment: Good practice is to declare a function once. Then, about performance, it is more about what that function does then it's declaration.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The best way to know is to test it. I could show you code where either one is "faster"

Answer (score 1):

You should use option 2.

This code sample show that there's a big performance impact when declaring the function multiple times

```js
var start = new Date();
let value = 0;
function add(a,b){
    return a + b;
}
for (var i=0;i<=100000000;i++){
    value += add(2, 5);
}
var end = new Date();
console.log(value);
var timeTaken = end.valueOf() - start.valueOf();
console.log("Took 1 " + timeTaken + "ms");
// Took 198ms

var start = new Date();
let value2 = 0;
for (var i=0;i<=100000000;i++){
    function add(a,b){
        return a + b;
    }
    value2 += add(2, 5);
}
var end = new Date();
console.log(value2);
var timeTaken = end.valueOf() - start.valueOf();
console.log("Took 2 " + timeTaken + "ms");
// Took 1127ms
```

Comment: Do you have any source for your claim "as it avoids multiple function evaluations (expensive) and allow function call optimisation on multiple calls."?

Comment: Your test is flawed: Your code doesn't call `a` (you call it `calculateTwoPlusFive`) thousands of times

Comment: indeed, fixed and it now show a huge difference

Comment: This difference is to be expected - any nested function requires  creating a new function obect for it, with a new set of environment records, each time it's outer function is called. The magnitude of performance difference will depend on the JavaScript engine being used and PC performance.

Comment: Your test is just wrong. Cause you redeclare add, the engine cannot optimize

Comment: Also the absolute difference between the two add calls is _18 nanoseconds_ (that's about 60 processor instructions) on average. You can easily get one of the examples way worse by preventing the engine from doing some optimizations, then you'll get the opposite results.

Comment: @traktor "any nested function requires creating a new function obect for it" does it? As long as the function accesses no variables from it's outer scope, or the function object is accessed as a reference, there is no difference between the function call to different function objects created at the same position. The engine could either inline those, or "move the function outside the inner scope".

Comment: @JonasWilms "...each time it's outer function is called" was intended to exclude the case of using a reference to function returned from inside a closure and, as well as in the additional case of passing a nested function as an argument to an external function, the compiler will not be able to inline the (nested) function code.  It could, I suppose, create a constant function object when compiling an outer function for nested functions that don't reference external variables using a non standard environmental record chain. I take your point that inline optimisation is implementation dependent.

Answer (score -2):

I'd go with Option 2. Defining a function thousands of times is dismal for performance, and unless you want multiple functions called `util` for some reason, there's no reason to worry about polluting the global scope. Local variables do tend to cause less lag, but it's not much of a difference.